# Dynamically created textbox does not allow edit, does not show cusor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery 1.12.3.

I have the following HTML structure (simplified for the sake of the question)

```js
$('.question').click(function() {
  var old_value = $(this).text();  //get existing value
  
  //create a dynamic text field and set its value to old_value
  var txt = $("<input type='text' class='txt' value='" + old_value + "'>");
  
  //clear the cell being edited and insert the dynamic textbox
  $(this).empty().append(txt);
  
  //automatically focus the textbox and select all text within
  txt.focus();
  txt.select();
});


// handle RETURN KEY event on the dynamic text field
$(document).on('keyup', '.txt', function(e) {
  
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // get the current value in the textbox
    var txt = $(this).val();
    
    var td = $(this).parent();
    
    //replace the content of the cell with the value from the textbox
    //this will cause the textbox to be remooved, which is what is needed
    td.html(txt);
    
    //now look for the next cell to edit
    var next_question = td.parent().next().find('.question').first();
    
    //fire the click event on the next cell.
    next_question.click();

    
  }

});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 350px;
}

td.question {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 250px;
}

.txt {
  color: red;
  background-color: #def;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Click on any of the value, then you will be able to edit.
<br> press RETURN key to move to and edit the next field.
<br><br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td class='question'>Ahmad</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td class='question'>Al-Mutawa</td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
    <td>Your Age</td>
    <td class='question'>22</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Basically, I am mimicking and Excel-Like-sheet behavior, where you can click any cell, edit it, press Enter and you automatically move to the cell below, and can instantly edit it as well.

From the snippet above, you can see the logic I have written to handle mouse click inside `.question` cells. That basically creates a dynamic `<input type=text>` field and replaces the content of the `<td>` with it (plus setting the input's value to the `old_value` from the cell).

This works perfectly on Chrome, but for some reason, does not behave the same way on Internet Explorer 11. The field is created automatically, the old value is set properly, but somehow, the blinking cursor disappears and when I try to type anything on the keyboard, the field value is blanked and no new characters are inserted. When I press the Enter key, I see the next field being edited, but the one I've just finished editing has a blank value, even though I tried to type on the keyboard.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you don't use style-less input fields instead of creating new ones?

Comment: @Justinas can you please elaborate? or point to document about that?

Comment: Remove background, border and other styles from input element when not active to only show text. `input:focus` can be used to select input element that has focus to apply CSS to look like active input